# flutter saves the file in the directory selected by the user

Tags: flutter

I use `file_picker` to get the directory path and `permission_handler` to get the storage permission, but when I finally save the file, it still fails. I don’t know where the problem is, I use Android

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;


        onPressed: () async {
          var storageStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
          if (storageStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
            storageStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
            if (storageStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
              return;
            }
          }

          var dpath = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
          if (dpath != null) {
            var p = path.join(dpath, 'test.jpg');
            try {
              var r = await http.readBytes(
                  'https://i.loli.net/2019/12/07/vVfLEsQy7TbehrW.jpg');
              try {
                await File(p).writeAsBytes(r);
              } catch (er) {
                print('save error: ' + er.message); // save error: Cannot open file
                print('save path: ' + p); // save path: /storage/emulated/0/.Android/test.jpg
                print(er); // FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/.Android/test.jpg' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

              }
            } catch (er) {
              print('download errro: ' + er.message);
            }
          }
        },
```

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path:
  file_picker: 2.0.7
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  http:
```

```sh
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at D:\my-tools\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (12 days ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\my-tools\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\my-tools\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: D:\my-tools\Android\AndroidStudio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at D:\my-tools\Android\AndroidStudio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G8750 (mobile) • c5976a52 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
```

Comment: Are you sure that path is correct? `.Android` looks like hidden directory. Try save file with some hardcoded path.

Comment: please also upload the logs when you try to save the file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I carefully checked the document of `permission_handler`, and changed the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in "android/app/build.gradle" file to `28`, and it can work normally when I run it again